# Volumes of solids using integration

Tags: integration

> Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region between the curves $y=x$, $y=2-x^2$, and $x=0$ about the $x$-axis.

How can I find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the blue shaded region in the pic below around the $x$-axis using integration?

[image]

Comment: What do you know about integration and solids of revolution?

Comment: @Arthur I'm a beginner in this section.

Comment: @Arthur I follow Calculus book by Anton, Bivens and Davis.

Comment: So what are the cross-sections of your solid when you slice perpendicular to the $x$-axis?

Answer (score 0):

If you revolve an ordinate of the graph of a nonnegative function about the $x$-axis, it gives you a disc. Thus, we want to calculate the area of this differential disc. This is given by $πy(x)^2\mathrm dx.$ This is what we integrate over the concerned interval to find our volume of revolution.

In case we have a region defined by two nonnegative graphs (like in your case), we apply it to each region separately and perform a subtraction of volumes. That is, suppose we have two functions $f$ and $g$ so that $f(x)\le g(x)$ on some interval. Then on that interval the solid of revolution of the region about the $x$-axis is given by the integral of $$\left(πg(x)^2-πf(x)^2\right)\mathrm dx.$$

In your case, take $g(x)=2-x^2$ and $f(x)=x.$ Can you continue now?